# jQuery using index()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am horrible at explaining on what I want, but ill give it a shot.

Ok here is html on the left side.

```
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Here is what is outputting on the right side.

```
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
```

I am trying to make it so when you click the first div on the left, the first div on the right appears, and when u click second div on the left, the second div on the right appears while all the other divs on the right are hidden again and so on. I know you can do it with the .index() in jQuery, but I was wondering if i can get some help on how to do it. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this?

#### Markup

```
<div class="left">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
</div>
<div class="right">
    <div class="block">Result 1</div>
    <div class="block">Result 2</div>
    <div class="block">Result 3</div>
    <div class="block">Result 4</div>
</div>
```

#### JS

```
$(function(){
   $('.left > div').on('click', function(){
        //Just show the respective block div based on the clicked index and hide its siblings that are visible.
        $('.block').eq($(this).index()).show().siblings('.block:visible').hide();
    });
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uB8ht/)**

With a little slide Effect

```
$(function () {
    $('.block').eq(0).show();
    $('.left > div').on('click', function () {
        var elemToShow = $('.block').eq($(this).index()); //Get the element to show
        $('.block:visible').stop().slideUp(1000, function () { // slide up the visible block div
            elemToShow.stop().slideDown(1000); // once the animation finishes shidedown the element to show
        });

    });
});
```

**[Demo Slide effect](http://jsfiddle.net/d7mxK/)**

**[Demo Fade effect](http://jsfiddle.net/6vXaG/)**

Comment: It would be even more convenient to hide the `.block`s before showing the one with the matched index...minimizes the code.

Comment: @Purmou Yeah it can go both ways.

Comment: Nice job in [very speedily] including the slide and fade examples. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you'll put a `left` class on those left `div`s:

```
var $blocks = $('.block'),
    $left = $('.left');

$('.left').click(function () {
    $blocks.hide().eq( $left.index(this) ).show();
});
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YddrP/

Comment: `$(this).index()` ? Or `$left.index(this)`

Answer (score 1):

Well, you first have to detect the click on the elements on the left. In the callback function, you'll have to find out the index of the clicked div and then `show()` the one on the right side whose index matches the number.

Let's say you have the left divs inside a container with the class `left` and the ones on the right inside `right`:

```js
$('.left').on('click', 'div', function(){ //bind the click event to the left divs
    $('.right div')                       // select all the divs inside .right
        .hide()                           // hide all the divs
        .eq( $(this).index() )            // select the one that matches the clicked index
        .show();                          // show it
});
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/4Gfqk/1/)'s a demo.

[Here](http://api.jquery.com/on/) is the documentation for `on()`.

[Here](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) is the documentation for `eq()`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can try .index() and :eq()
.index() returns the numeric index of an element, while :eq() returns the element by a numeric index.

Assume the left divs are inside a outer div with class 'left', and right divs inside 'right'

```
$('.left div').click(function () {
    $('.right div').hide();
    var i = $('.left div').index(this);
    $('.right div:eq(' + i + ')').show()
});
```